# Remove apk from beta testing which has published on google play

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have published apk on beta testing on google play but not on Production. There is no any apk on Production. Now I want to remove that apk from beta testing. 
Can anyone please help me How can I remove published apk on beta testing?

Comment: you can not delete that apk but you can move that apk to directly on Production or on Alpha testing

Comment: Thanks for giving information But I don't want to move that apk on Production. The reason I have fixed some issues in app which I got from beta testing. Now I want to upload new apk directly to Production but it say   you have to increase version code for this but I don't want to do that. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: Why not? You just have to increase the version code, not the version string. Only the latter is visible to users.

Comment: Thanks for giving information.

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove the existing app from alpha, beta etc. But if you found any issue and you fixed it then just increase the version and upload apk on same track (alpha, beta) that you previously uploaded and then previous version of apk will be archived automatically (overwritten by new apk) and no need to delete the apk.

And then move that apk from one track to another and finally to production.

Hope it helps you and resolve your problem.